# How to lock several machines with one command issued from one of them?

Tags: windows, synergy

I'm using Synergy to use my three PCs with only one keyboard and mouse. My problem is that when I press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to lock a PC, it always locks the main PC (the one functioning as the Synergy server.) I would like to have a command to lock/unlock all three PCs at once.

Does anyone know of a tool or have a suggestion on how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command `rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation` to lock the current workstation so you should be able to use [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) to run it on the other two machines.  If you were to put the three commands into a batch file that should do the job.